# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

In my node app, I have routes called `index` and `home`. While trying to redirect from index to home route it throws the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

Here is the code:

```
app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/home');
})
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome Home !!');
})
```

Comment: The code you've shown thus far will not create that error by itself, there has to be some other part of the code that is the source of the error. This is why posting the full stack trace can be beneficial in identifying where the real cause may lie.

Comment: Yep, I agree with mscdex.  There's nothing wrong with the code you show and it will not create the error you describe.  Usually this error is caused by improper handling of async requests such a `fs.readFile()` or database operations or other network requests.  You will have to show us the REAL code you're using for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace '/index' with "/index". It works fine after that.